# compare value to array element

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++

when i get user input `cin >> x;` and `cin >> y;`

I want to then compare this to an array "Location cord" `L1[i][j]`, but when i use an if statement
- `if (x && y == L1[i][j])`
- `if (x == L1[i] && y == L1[j])`

Im not getting the result of "HIT" which is what i need.
This is a sort of minesweeper project. Any help, or pointers would be much appreciated!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

char L1[8][8], L2[16][16], L3[24][24]; // grid location of cords
char B1[8][8], B2[16][16], B3[24][24]; // grid location of bombs
int i, j;

using namespace std;

// load and print grids L1 L2 L3
void loadgrid_L1()
{
    for ( i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            L1[i][j] = 'X';
        }
    }
}
void printgrid_L1() 
{
    for ( i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            cout << L1[i][j];
        }
        cout << ("\n");
    }
}

void loadgrid_L2()
{
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 16; j++)
        {
            L2[i][j] = 'X';
        }
    }
}
void printgrid_L2()
{
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 16; j++)
        {
            cout << L2[i][j];
        }
        cout << ("\n");
    }
}

void loadgrid_L3()
{
    for (i = 0; i < 24; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 24; j++)
        {
            L3[i][j] = 'X';
        }
    }
}
void printgrid_L3()
{
    for (i = 0; i < 24; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 24; j++)
        {
            cout << L3[i][j];
        }
        cout << ("\n");
    }
}

void bomb1() 
{
    L1[1][5] = 'O';
}

void bomb2()
{
    L2[3][4] = 'O';
}

void bomb3()
{
    L3[6][6] = 'O';
}

void menu() //need to work on this section
{
    string lvl, x, y;

    cout << "Please select a lvl to play L1, L2, L3 " << endl;
    getline(cin, lvl);

    if (lvl == "L1")
    {
        loadgrid_L1();
        //moved bomb() from here

        cout << "Please enter your co-ordinates for your move" << endl;
        cout << "Cord 1: "; 
        getline(cin, x);
        cout << "Cord 2: ";
        getline(cin, y);

        if (x == L1[i])
        {
            cout << "HIT!" << endl;
        }
        else if (x != L1[i])
        {
            cout << "SUCCESS!" << endl;
        }

        bomb1();
        printgrid_L1();


    }
    else if (lvl == "L2")
    {
        loadgrid_L2();
        bomb2();
        printgrid_L2();
    }
    else if (lvl == "L3")
    {
        loadgrid_L3();
        bomb3();
        printgrid_L3();
    }
    else if ((lvl != "L1") && (lvl != "L2") && (lvl != "L3"))
    {
        cout << "You must pick a lvl" << endl;
        while ((lvl != "L1") && (lvl != "L2") && (lvl != "L3"))
        {
            getline(cin, lvl);
            if (lvl == "L1")
            {
                loadgrid_L1();
                bomb1();
                printgrid_L1();
            }
            else if (lvl == "L2")
            {
                loadgrid_L2();
                bomb2();
                printgrid_L2();
            }
            else if (lvl == "L3")
            {
                loadgrid_L3();
                bomb3();
                printgrid_L3(); // needs to stop
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{   
    menu();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The expression `lvl != "L1" || "L2" || "L3"` does not work as you expect it do to. It check if `lvl != "L1"` is false, and if it is then it check is the expression `"L2"` is false, which it will never be.

Comment: Another problem, you use indexing of your arrays correct in the `loadgrid_L1` function and the `printgrid` functions, but not in the other `loadgrid` functions. Why?

Comment: completely by passed that on will fix that now with the printgrid and loadgrid thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can easily change each of your loadgrid & printgrid functions to be 2 single functions as such:

```
void loadgrid( unsigned int lvl ) {
    if ( lvl < 0 || lvl > 3 ) {
        std::cout << "Error: invalid level entered: " << lvl << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    int size = 0;
    if ( lvl == 1 )
        size = 8;
    else if ( lvl == 2 ) 
        size = 16;
    else if ( lvl == 3 )
        size = 24;

    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < size; j++ ) {
            if ( lvl == 1 ) 
                L1[i][j] = 'X';
            else if ( lvl == 2 )
                L2[i][j] = 'X';
            else if ( lvl == 3 )
                L3[i][j] = 'X';               
        }
    }   
}
```

And you can follow the same pattern above for print grid.

Then when you call the function you just pass what lvl you want to load and or print.

Comment: That is great thank you, very clean, however I am going to keep that aside until i figure out the comparison part of this program then i can work on cleaning it up, but great suggestion thank you